proc del GAM - GAMGetBackendMenu
como estan, Estoy tratando de buscar ese proc el cual aparece en el video de unanimo para realizar los submenu pero no lo encuentro en \Library\GAM ni en la kb donde esta instalado GAM. Necesito desplegar el menu con submenus.
Gracias

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
